# Non virtual version of virtual class

Tags: c++, virtual, c++11

Lets say we have the following two class definitions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class A
{
public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  virtual void f() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
  int i;
};
```

Here `sizeof(B) == 8`, presumably 4 the virtual pointer and 4 for the `int`.

Now lets say we make an array of B, like so:

```
std::array<B, 10> x;
```

Now we get `sizeof(x) == 80`.

If my understanding is correct, all method calls on elements of `x` are resolved statically, as we know the type at compile time. Unless we do something like `A* p = &x[i]` I don't see a need to even store the virtual pointer.

Is there a way to create an object of type B without a virtual pointer if you know it is not going to be used?

i.e. a template type `nonvirtual<T>` which does not contain a virtual pointer, and cannot be pointed to by a subtype of T?

Comment: Why would you want one? If you derived `B` from `A` using virtual functions and such, then you must have had some reason for doing so. You clearly want code that uses `A` to treat `B` like `A`s. So what would you gain from this?

Comment: Why would you want this? would you really benefit from stripping the virtual pointer? if you will do, you should consider make another `B` class that's not virtual.

Comment: @Dani: I would want the ability to use both homogeneous and non-homogeneous collections whilst not paying for what I don't use in the case of homogeneous collections.

Comment: @Clinton if a single pointer in a class which is believe is more than one `int` is a significant loss, you should read some volumes on optimization. if you still aren't convinced, make your project in assembly, you won't believe how much less memory it takes (and run-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an object of type B without a virtual pointer if you know it is not going to be used?

No. Objects are what they are. A virtual object is virtual, always.

After all, you could do this:

```
A *a = &x[2];
a->f();
```

That is perfectly legitimate and legal code. And C++ has to allow it. The type `B` is virtual, and it has a certain size. You can't make a type be a different type based on where it is used.

Comment: I understand `B` is what it is, but what about defining `nonvirtual<B>` as a completely new type? Is that doable?

Comment: @Clinton No. Templates are incapable of doing that, because they are incapable of forwarding every possible function to the object in question. And even if they could, they would have to create a `B` in order to hold that object's data. And `B` is virtual.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: half of STL cannot be done without some compiler intervention. he asks if such compiler intervention exists for what he wants.

Comment: @Dani What half of STL is that? There are certain metaprogramming traits that are difficult to do without some compiler support. But there are many cross-platform implementations of STL types and algorithms. And no, there is no "compiler intervention" that causes one particular use of type `B` to not be the same as another use of `B`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: try `typeid`, `move`.

Comment: @Dani `typeid` is filed under the part of the C++ library specification specifically called "language support library". `move` is nothing more than a fancy _cast_; it requires zero compiler support. Also, `typeid` is far from "half of STL". Indeed, the "language support library" part is rather small and short.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: the "small" language support library is the whole compiler, which is 18 MB on my platform. and the "big" standard library is 5 MB and that's including opengl and friends.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3778/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-dani)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here, but I've found that the following does the job, by splitting A into it's virtual and non-virtual components:

```
enum is_virtual
{
  VIRTUAL,
  STATIC
};

template <is_virtual X>
class A;

template<>
class A<STATIC>
{
};

template<>
class A<VIRTUAL> : public A<STATIC>
{
public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
  virtual ~A() {}
};

template <is_virtual X>
class B : public A<X>
{
public:
  void f() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
  int i;
};
```

The important thing here is that in `B<>` don't specify `f()` as virtual. That way it will be virtual if the class inherits `A<VIRTUAL>`, but not virtual if it inherits `A<STATIC>`. Then we can do the following:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(B<STATIC>) << std::endl; // 4
  std::cout << sizeof(B<VIRTUAL>) << std::endl; // 8
  std::array<B<STATIC>, 10> x1;
  std::array<B<VIRTUAL>, 10> x2;
  std::cout << sizeof(x1) << std::endl; // 40
  std::cout << sizeof(x2) << std::endl; // 80
}
```

Comment: And how is that different than if you had defined 2 versions of B, one inheriting A and another not inheriting A?

Comment: @David: If A had non-pure virtual methods (and data) then not inheriting A would result in these not being available.

Comment: Amusing. I agree this is a solution to some constrained version of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a nice one to have, but I can't think of any way to revoke virtual members or avoid storing the virtual pointer.

You could probably do some nasty hacks by keeping a buffer that's the size of B without the virtual pointer, and play with casts and such. But is all undefined behavior, and platform dependant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it won't work in any normal sense as the code inside the method calls expects the virtual pointer to be in the class definition.

I suppose you could copy/paste all of A and B's code into a new class but that gets to be a maintenance headache fast.